# Module '"node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'OnActivate'

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

**Behavior**

Following the documentation at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html I add the following line

```
import {OnActivate, RouteSegment, RouteTree} from "@angular/router";
```

Then i run ng serve and get the following errors

```
ERROR in [default] /Users/~/src/app/stock-item/stock-item.component.ts:3:8 
Module '"/Users/~/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'OnActivate'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/~/src/app/stock-item/stock-item.component.ts:3:20 
Module '"/Users/~/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouteSegment'.

ERROR in [default] /Users/~/src/app/stock-item/stock-item.component.ts:3:34 
Module '"/Users/~/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouteTree'.
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you are using older version of angular and in latest angular version `OnActivate`, `RouteSegment` and `RouteTree` are deprecated so you have to make change in your code according to it. You can check angular [router api reference](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?query=router) . You can also check [angular change log](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to check from which version version `OnActivate`, `RouteSegment` and `RouteTree` are are deprecated .

Comment: I still haven't found a way around it, I'm really new to angular 2

Comment: please share your package.json and file code in which you have used `OnActivate`, `RouteSegment` and `RouteTree`.